# JSON schema anyOf properties required with a specific error message

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm trying to implement JSON validation using Python `jsonschema` library.
I want to have at least one of the three properties to be required in my JSON.
I'm using `anyOf` subschema to achieve that.
This rule should apply to different sets of properties, therefore I'm enclosing `anyOf`s within `allOf`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "a": {"type": "string"},
        "b": {"type": "string"},
        "c": {"type": "string"},
        "x": {"type": "string"},
        "y": {"type": "string"},
        "z": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "allOf": [
        "anyOf": [
            {"required": ["a"]},
            {"required": ["b"]},
            {"required": ["c"]}
        ],
        "anyOf": [
            {"required": ["x"]},
            {"required": ["y"]},
            {"required": ["z"]}
        ]
    ]
}
```

If I try to validate empty JSON `{}` against that schema I'm getting a generic error message `{} is not valid under any of the given schemas`.
Is there a way to get a more specific (custom) message, e.g. `One of 'x', 'y', 'z' is required`?

Answer (score 0):

How about using additionalProperties: false minProperties: 1?

Comment: This would give ```{} does not have enough properties``` error.

Comment: Right, that meets your validation requirements